# "hello world" spring boot app created with initializer wont run, just exit with no errors

Tags: spring-boot

I created a spring boot app using the initializer, choosing the following settings:

1. version: 3.1.5
2. lang: groovy
3. package: jar
4. java: 17
5. dependencies: spring boot dev tools, lombok, spring web, spring session, spring security, spring data JAP (which I am guessing i need to connect to a database), H2 Db

I then open this project in intellij, set the project structure java version to 17, and it shows no errors in "problems".

However, when I hit the "RUN" button in intellij, it compiles then exits without starting tomcat.  No idea how to debug this, or to work around this to get a blank spring boot project which will run.

The output is this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=56487:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.9.3/junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/simon/dev/nutmix-github/bomg/target/test-classes:/Users/simon/dev/nutmix-github/bomg/target/classes:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-aop-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.20/aspectjweaver-1.9.20.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/6.0.13/spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.2.13.Final/hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/2.0.1/jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.5.3.Final/jboss-logging-3.5.3.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/6.0.6.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/io/smallrye/jandex/3.0.5/jandex-3.0.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.9/byte-buddy-1.14.9.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.3/jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.3/jaxb-core-4.0.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/2.0.1/angus-activation-2.0.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/4.0.3/txw2-4.0.3.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.1.2/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.2.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/jakarta/inject/jakarta.inject-api/2.0.1/jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.10.1/antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/3.1.5/spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/3.1.5/spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.0.13/spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.13/spring-context-6.0.13.jar:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.13/spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.13/spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.9/slf4j-api-2.0.9.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/6.0.13/spring-aspects-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-security-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.11/logback-classic-1.4.11.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.11/logback-core-1.4.11.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.20.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.20.0.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.20.0/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.9/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.9.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.13/spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/6.1.5/spring-security-config-6.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/6.1.5/spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.13/spring-expression-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-json-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.15.3/jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.15.3/jackson-annotations-2.15.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.15.3/jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.15.3/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.15.3/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.15.3/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.15/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.15/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.15.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/10.1.15/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.15.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.13/spring-web-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.11.5/micrometer-observation-1.11.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.11.5/micrometer-commons-1.11.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.13/spring-webmvc-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apache/groovy/groovy/4.0.15/groovy-4.0.15.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/session/spring-session-core/3.1.3/spring-session-core-3.1.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.13/spring-jcl-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/3.1.5/spring-boot-devtools-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.1.5/spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.1.5/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/2.1.214/h2-2.1.214.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.30/lombok-1.18.30.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-test/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-test-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test/3.1.5/spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/3.1.5/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.8.0/json-path-2.8.0.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.1/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.2/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.4.11/json-smart-2.4.11.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/2.4.11/accessors-smart-2.4.11.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.3/asm-9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.24.2/assertj-core-3.24.2.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest/2.2/hamcrest-2.2.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-5.9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-api-5.9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.9.3/junit-platform-commons-1.9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-params-5.9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.9.3/junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/5.3.1/mockito-core-5.3.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.14.9/byte-buddy-agent-1.14.9.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/3.3/objenesis-3.3.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/5.3.1/mockito-junit-jupiter-5.3.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.5.1/jsonassert-1.5.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.13/spring-core-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/6.0.13/spring-test-6.0.13.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/xmlunit/xmlunit-core/2.9.1/xmlunit-core-2.9.1.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-test/6.1.5/spring-security-test-6.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/6.1.5/spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:/Users/simon/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/6.1.5/spring-security-crypto-6.1.5.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 @w@/private/var/folders/0m/w52yvpkn4lngbwfb8slbf_m80000gn/T/idea_working_dirs_junit.tmp @/private/var/folders/0m/w52yvpkn4lngbwfb8slbf_m80000gn/T/idea_junit.tmp -socket56486
23:05:12.598 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.ohds.bomg.BomgApplicationTests]: BomgApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
23:05:12.645 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.ohds.bomg.BomgApplication for test class com.ohds.bomg.BomgApplicationTests
23:05:12.783 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener -- Restart disabled due to context in which it is running

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.5)

2023-10-30T23:05:12.875+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] com.ohds.bomg.BomgApplicationTests       : Starting BomgApplicationTests using Java 17.0.9 with PID 27787 (started by simon in /Users/simon/dev/nutmix-github/bomg)
2023-10-30T23:05:12.875+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] com.ohds.bomg.BomgApplicationTests       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-30T23:05:13.129+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-30T23:05:13.139+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-30T23:05:13.321+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-30T23:05:13.405+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:871bde75-74fc-4a36-bd8c-54c89f860bfb user=SA
2023-10-30T23:05:13.405+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-10-30T23:05:13.426+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-10-30T23:05:13.451+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.13.Final
2023-10-30T23:05:13.452+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-10-30T23:05:13.564+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-10-30T23:05:13.708+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2023-10-30T23:05:13.709+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-30T23:05:13.778+01:00  WARN 27787 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-10-30T23:05:13.952+01:00  WARN 27787 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: c16c063a-3661-4fbd-8224-80b00d2c0425

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2023-10-30T23:05:14.020+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@6719f206, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5ae16aa, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@12ebfb2d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7bde704a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@23263ba, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@28269c65, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3605ab16, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@27a6384b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@344a065a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@333a2df2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@629600d7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@61c145cb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3051e476, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@76134251, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@76105ac0]
2023-10-30T23:05:14.045+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [           main] com.ohds.bomg.BomgApplicationTests       : Started BomgApplicationTests in 1.263 seconds (process running for 1.809)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2023-10-30T23:05:14.394+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-30T23:05:14.395+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-10-30T23:05:14.396+01:00  INFO 27787 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ohds</groupId>
    <artifactId>bomg</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bomg</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                            <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is what the generated main class looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class BomgApplication {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BomgApplication, args)
    }
    
}
```

When I create a project with initializer, if I chose Maven+Java it fails, if I chose gradle+groovy it works, but if I choose Maven and groovy, it fails.

Still cant find any way to get a spring boot project to run on a mac with maven or java.

Maybe Im trying to run the project in the wrong way? Im choosing "run" from the "run" menu. Then it pops up something asking what it should run the first time you do it, and the only option it gives is "all in Bomg" or something similar.  The various tutorials I have found on spring using intellij dont mention how to setup profiles to run the app, they just say run it.

Comment: What happens when you run without modifying anything? Also, show your code.

Comment: Hi, the code is at the top: I just added the " @GetMapping("/hello")" to the existing main so that it would output something (hello world).  If I revert this change, I get the same issue (tomcat doesnt start, just exits with no errors)

Comment: Tomcat appears to be missing. It should be there as you have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`. This problem can occur when Maven has corrupted a Tomcat jar file when it downloaded the dependency. Trying purging Maven's local repository (`./mvnw dependency:purge-local-repository`) and building your application again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried going ./mvnw dependency:purge-local-repository but I get the same error when i run the project after doing this unfortuatnely.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was missing.  Unlike VS Code, in intellij you have to tell it where the main class is.  You have to create a run configuration and specify the class to run and JDK you want it to use:

[image]

Then you can run the project and it will start tomcat.